# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, nan, increment

Please! help me I am super confused.

why

```
true++
```

results

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation"

but

```
undefined++
```

is

> NaN

and If I do this.

```
let a = true;
a++;
a;
```

the answer is 2.

Comment: `true` can't be changed ... `a` can (true = true + 1) ..... though ... undefined ... hmmm - I think for historic reasons you can say `undefined=1` for example ... it USED to actually change the value of `undefined` if I remember correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only increment something you can assign to, that is, a variable, an array member or an object property. You can not increment constants. `true` is a constant, so `true++` is a syntax error, and so are for example `true=5` or `12++` or `13=7`.

`undefined` is *not* a constant, it's traditionally a property of the global object (because of the bug in some early JS version which it's too late to fix). Therefore the parser doesn't complain about `undefined++`, although this expression doesn't make sense (and raises an error in the strict mode).

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but couldn't the value of `undefined` actually be changed! I'm almost sure some very early JS implementations had that "quirk"